# How to print html tag at laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I want to print Html tag.

I can print only text now.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
require 'G:/xampp/htdocs/print/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;

class PrintController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){       

        $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("eees");
        $printer = new Printer($connector);
        try {
            $printer = new Printer($connector);
            $printer -> text('Hello World');
            $printer -> cut();
        } finally {
            $printer -> close();
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's kind of stupid to copy-paste all this into each document, and painstakingly go in and change each page separately if I just want to change one word or tag. Is there a way I can put this in template.htm (or something similar) and have php code take this and insert everything from the requested file inside of the  tag? I don't know a lot of php, so this is probably a piece of cake for you gurus, but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you actually using Laravel? In which case, take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade.

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, you should add the logic to `Controller.php`, then you will be able to use it in any other controller that extends Controller